# Accessing GUI of UNIX from LINUX /RHEL

Tags: linux

Is there any free available tool or X Window System tool like Exceed for Accessing the GUI of UNIX from LINUX/RHEL.

Comment: cygwin/X + ssh X forwarding

Comment: Please clarify. What Unix? What is it running on? How are you connecting? I assume you mean two different computers? What is Exceed? Are the machines on the same network? You need to explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: xpra, ssh, nx, vnc, rdp, etc?

Answer (score 1):

To access another system's desktop you can use either VNC (client and server) or you can use [XRDP](http://www.xrdp.org/). XRDP is a wrapper that provides a layer similar to the remote desktop protocol (RDP) on Windows. To make connections to a system that's running the daemon (`xrdp`) you can use one called `xfreerdp`, there are of course others.